# On Bryce Seligman DeWitt's Name Change

Tags: physics, biographical-details, physicists

Weinberg, in his memoir on Bryce Seligman DeWitt (available at https://www.nasonline.org/publications/biographical-memoirs/memoir-pdfs/dewitt-bryce.pdf) states that

> In 1950 two major but totally unrelated developments occurred in his life. First, he became engaged to be married to Cecile Morette, a young French physicist who was in her second postdoctoral year at the institute. Second, at the urging of their father, he and his three brothers began the legal procedures for changing their surname to a name from their mother’s side of the family. The younger boys
> were, or had been, at school in the eastern United States, and all had encountered repeated misunderstandings and false assumptions based solely on their surname, something that had seldom occurred in California. (p.5)

and

> [A potential professorship offer to DeWitt], however, was vetoed by Felix Bloch, who upon learning that Bryce had changed his surname 20 years earlier, refused to allow the offer to proceed. (p.10)

One can find similar passages elsewhere (e.g. DeWitt-Morrette's memoirs).

**Question:** What were the "repeated misunderstandings and false assumptions" in question, and why was the name change taken so negatively by Bloch?

Comment: I can only *speculate*: The last name Seligman suggests Jewish roots, and from the biography linked in the question it appears that while DeWitt had some Jewish ancestry, his family was Christian. Best I know, anti-semitic prejudice was widespread on (but not limited to) the East Coast of the United States at that time. See the excellent 1947 movie "[Gentleman's Agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentleman%27s_Agreement)" for examples. Bloch was Jewish and may have (*speculation!*) resented a name change designed to hide Jewish ancestry. The name DeWitt suggests Dutch or French origin.

Comment: @njuffa Thank you; I had speculated similarly.